# prometheus query range when change hours in start time change all values in this period

Tags: prometheus, promql

I use the query below to get the sum of daily values pve_network_receive_bytes.
pve_network_receive_bytes is a gauge type.

`sum_over_time(increase(pve_network_receive_bytes{id="000"}[1d] offset-24h )[1d:1d])`

When using the API query range and setting the start value as `23/12/2022 00:06:40`
and the end value is `30/12/2022 00:00:00`, it seems the response value is correct.

Step value is `24 * 60 * 60 (1d)`.

```
[
[1671754000 ,"32061451.224170864"],
[1671840400 ,"271737134.5858656"],
[1671926800 ,"418052632.5820455"],
[1672013200 ,"326222568.86264974"],
[1672099600 ,"31086710.278712504"],
[1672186000 ,"82149572.07848585"],
[1672272400 ,"591449366.1816287"]
]
```

But when changing the start value to `23/12/2022 00:00:00` the response value change in all the days to this

```
 [ 
 [1671840000 ,"303798585.8100365"],
 [1671926400 ,"689789767.167911"],
 [1672012800 ,"744275201.4446952"],
 [1672099200 ,"357309279.14136225"],
 [1672185600 ,"113236282.35719836"],
 [1672272000 ,"673598938.2601146"],
 [1672358400 ,"833346458.2045493"]
 ]
```

Why did this happen all days of the list? Did not just change the first-day value.

The result with start time : `23/12/2022 00:00:01`
with just one second different is same as first result  :

```
[
[1671753601,"32061451.224170864"],
[1671840001,"271737134.5858656"],
[1671926401,"418052632.5820455"],
[1672012801,"326222568.86264974"],
[1672099201,"31086710.278712504"],
[1672185601,"82149572.07848585"],
[1672272001,"591449366.1816287"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

These changes are completely logical.

According to the explanation of the Prometheus [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) `sum_over_time` is:

`the sum of all values in the specified interval`

Therefore, the sum of values from `24/12/2022 00:06:40` to `25/12/2022 00:06:40`  is not the same as the sum of values from `24/12/2022 00:00:00` to `25/12/2022 00:00:00`

So `24/12/2022 00:06:40` to `25/12/2022 00:06:40` is not same period `24/12/2022 00:00:00` to `25/12/2022 00:00:00`

Comment: end time and step  is the same value in two request , and why when use 23/12/2022 00:06:40 value is  correct for every day from 00:00 to 24:00

Comment: step is same in two requests but end time is not

Comment: I test with start  ```23/12/2022 00:00:01```  and the result is same as 23/12/2022 00:06:40, this query calculates sum over every day from 00:00 to 23:59